# Laravel fatal error on forgotpassword

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

Getting strange fatal error on laravel forgotpassword.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

Screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/i8nt3q

Any help will be appreciated.

Laravel Version: "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
PHp version 7.1

Comment: What's your php version?

Comment: It looks like you're running PHP 7.1 code on a lower version. Specifically, v4 of `symfony/css-selector`.

Comment: It's better if you show your code here instead of linking to a screenshot. That way we can see it more easily.

Comment: Updated above post

Comment: `?` is used to denote a nullable parameter or return type, which was introduced in 7.1. Are you absolutely sure the server is running PHP 7.1?

Comment: @Kyrre 
php version
https://prnt.sc/i8o6cc